# Double click event on amCharts

Tags: events, amcharts

I have some actions, which should occur on a double-click event on a chart. However, I'm not able to find an event for this and any double-click implementations I see have been done by observing a particular click-duration between two single-click events. Any simpler way than this is appreciated.

Comment: There are no built-in events for doubleclick. Maybe you could explain what in particularly are you trying to achieve. Maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: @martynasma I want to perform an action [navigate to another page along with some click context] on double-click. I have already used the single-click [ clickgraphitem] event to perform drilldown, hence want to use double-click for navigation.

Comment: How about implementing this logic manually. Just use a timeout and check if the second click is on the same element.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z5e91jrL/).

Comment: @gerric That is exactly what i mean by  "observing a particular click-duration between two single-click events" in my description of the question.Looking for a simpler way.

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil well this is how a double click works. I can't think of an easier way. If there would be an API for this, then it would presumably do exactly this, maybe just in a more generic way and bound to `amCharts` classes not DOM-Elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@martynasma, @gerric . Implemented as per your suggestion using a time-out.Though additionally, this code needs a check to see if two consecutive clicks are on same target.

```
var ts = (new Date()).getTime();
if ((ts -  Window.lastClick) < 1000) 
{
   if (Window.clickTimeout) 
   {
      clearTimeout(Window.clickTimeout);
   }
   console.log("double click");
   Window.lastClick = 0;
}
else
{
   Window.clickTimeout = setTimeout(function () 
   {
     console.log("single click");
   },1000);
}
Window.lastClick = ts;
```